# ReactJS MaterialUI can I pass a parameter of an element into a function in another parameter?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

Using ReactJS + MaterialUI with [formsy-material-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formsy-material-ui).

For example if I wanted to pass in the value of `blah` into the `defaultSelected` value in this radio button group.

```
<FormsyRadioGroup name="radio"
    className="radioBtns"
    blah="blah blah"
    defaultSelected={someFunction(blah)}
>
```

thanks

Comment: Do you see it as a `prop` on the class? https://github.com/mbrookes/formsy-material-ui/blob/master/src/FormsyRadioGroup.jsx

Comment: It's not, but just because I'm curious, how would it be done if it were? And because it's not a prop on the class, does that make this not doable?

Comment: This class looks to pass arbitrary props (`rest`) down to material-ui's RadioButtonGroup (https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/d6e11115b58e47287884f44faa06a3892048cf7b/src/RadioButton/RadioButtonGroup.js), so feasibly you should be able to pass `defaultSelected` since its a prop on `RadioButtonGroup`

Comment: What's the meaning of it? You cant store value passed to `blah` prop in a variable, and pass this variable to as the argument to `someFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

If 'blah' is static, why don't you simply use
`defaultSelected={someFunction("blah blah")}`
and if it's dynamically getting a value, pass in the state or variable from where 'blah' is getting its value, to the function.
`blah={this.state.blah}`
`defaultSelected={someFunction(this.state.blah)}`